# Is it possible to create a purely online library?

Tags: digital-libraries

Many subscription databases only offer subscriptions to libraries and not to individuals.

Do the legal requirements of registering as a library require the library to have a physical building where patrons can attend, or is it possible for a library to only offer services online, through a website/web portal?

Comment: What does "registering as a library" even mean? How does having a building mean anything?

Comment: Where I work most folks use the library virtually. The books are still there, but all journals are online. Few people visit since you can request a physical book from your computer and get it the next day at your desk.

Comment: This feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the real problem you want to solve is that you want access to some database, are blocked because the database only offers libraries to subscribe, and now you're wondering if you can become a library somehow without needing to have a library building. Is that right?

Comment: And note that the typical subscription fees for common databases are out of range for most of the individuals around the world (tens of thousand dollars/year).

Comment: Banks do it; I have a savings account at such a bank.  However, more relevant comments are likely to be those of Bryan Krause and Massimo Ortolando.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yeah, my real question is how I can feasibly and conveniently get access to any information resource I want because I depend on them and for too long I have felt like getting access to academic databases has too many hurdles. I wish there was just one place where you could use any database that exists. Right now all I know is you can search for which libraries have that resource and then you can join each one. Some might be far away, even in other countries. Or maybe national libraries are better, the Library of Congress for example?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking whether an editor would accept your hypothetical online library as a library in their dealings with them. This would depend on how analogous it would be to a brick-and-mortar library. For example, an online university would probably qualify, but a free-lance library set up for the purpose of circumventing business restrictions will not.

Ultimately, the decision on what would be considered a library would lay with the editorial house.

Comment: I actually feel really strongly that libraries need to go way more digital-native. Their relationship to society is extremely different from what it used to be. There is arguably almost no need for physical books, public computers or even a physical location. The online media they provide is through slow, ambivalent-quality apps and web portals, and the selection is arbitrarily spotty when in theory a library patron could want any material at some point. There should be a new online-only library with way more convenience, a very fast, usable app like Netflix.

Comment: Anyway, here is a useful document I was looking for about how to actually formally register: https://www.nysl.nysed.gov/libdev/register/index.html

Comment: @peters "There is arguably almost no need for physical books" This is a horrific sentiment, and if the goal with your proposed online library is to eliminate the need for physical books, then very few academics will (thankfully) ever support this project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but there are many issues. A publisher will be willing to sell (yes sell) subscriptions to harvard.edu but probably not to flybyniteredistributors.com. The former is established, known to be reputable, and will adhere to any contracts signed. The latter is a risk, if you know what I mean.

But publishers don't *give* titles to libraries and they restrict distributions. For some (many) it is one copy at a time. For many it is a maximum (usually quite low) number of distributions before a renewal is required. I'm guessing that the low totals are based on the short expected lifetime of print books, not the long life of an ebook.

You can find [some of the costs and restrictions here](https://goodereader.com/blog/e-book-news/here-is-a-breakdown-of-how-much-libraries-pay-for-ebooks-from-publishers).

But, if you are an established reputable business or organization, then a publisher would be happy to work with you on your library. So, IBM.com can do it and will be trusted to pay the fees and observe the limitations. Likewise [www.nypl.org](http://www.nypl.org). The building itself is not relevant in either case. The expectation of honesty and stability are.

My local town library distributes ebooks, though it doesn't carry academic journals. There are similar restrictions, with the files becoming unreadable after a certain period, just as if you have to return a printed copy. Then, that "copy" can be loaned to another for a period. In this case, the costs are funded by town taxes.

Note that in theory information could be free. But there are many "frictions" in the system, including royalties on books, costs of storage (even of ebooks), electricity, costs of software systems, security, and many others. The various costs need to be covered. So, in practice, information isn't always free.